# What scripts do I use to be able to convert a binary number into decimal?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing a basic webpage in Dreamweaver that will let users convert a binary number of any length into decimal, for example, user inputs 10101, and the page returns 21.

I think I have the algorithm worked out but I don't know how to make it work.

This is what I had in mind:

> n = number of digits in binary number
>
> d = specific digit in binary number (we should be able to identify each digit from right to left)
>
> p = exponent

```
GET n

SET p = 0

SET totalDecimal = 0

FOR index = 0 to n-1

GET d[index]

SET decimal[index] = d[index]*2^p 

SET p = p+1

SET totalDecimal = totalDecimal + decimal[index] 

ENDFOR

DISPLAY totalDecimal
```

> This should calculate something like this:
>
> d[0]*2^0 + d[1]*2^1 + d[2]*2^2 + d[3]*2^3 + d[4]*2^4

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The only programming language that works natively in a webpage is JavaScript. It has a built-in function to do this: `parseInt("10101", 2)` will give you `21`.

Comment: This seems to be a homework. JavaScript can attain what you want.